# Can I perform an optional static_assert if the parameter is known at compile time?

Tags: c++, assert

I have a function that only accepts unsigned integers greater than 0 and has a debug assert to check it:

```
void foo(unsigned int x) {
    assert(x > 0);
}
```

Is it possible to add a `static_assert` here, so that the code still compiles and also accepts parameters that are not compile time constants?

```
foo(0); // compilation error
foo(1); // fine
foo(get_x_from_user()); // fine
```

I know I could make x a template parameter, but I would much prefer to keep this style of call: `foo(5);` rather than `foo<5>();`.

I was thinking there might be a way to pull this off with a custom integer type, but I couldn't get very far on that route. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `static_assert` is for values known at compile time, while `assert` runs at runtime.

Comment: I guess the `x` must be a `constexpr` in order to assert it using `static_assert`. I'm not sure you can make a runtime value returned by `get_x_from_user()` to be a `constexpr`.

Comment: @CinCout, I'm aware..?

Comment: My point being, `get_x_from_user()` 's value cannot be known at compile time.

Comment: @CinCout that's the entire point of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible without introducing some kind of templating, for example :

```
template<int T>
class CustomInt
{
public:
    static constexpr int value = T;
};

template<int val>
void check(CustomInt<val> /*k*/)
{
    static_assert(CustomInt<val>::value > 0, "error!");
    check(val);
}

void check(int k)
{
    std::cout << "check";
}

int s()
{
    volatile int x = 5;
    return x;
}

int main() {
    check(CustomInt<0>());
    check(s());
    return 0;
}
```

This just moves the templating to the custom type though.

Comment: I didn't like this idea first, but I think that using `std::integral_constant` in place of `CustomInt` and simply providing this as an overload is actually a nice solution (and gives an option for the user to choose if they want static_assert). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you stick to `foo(12)` you can't. Because you want the compiler to know the value of a function parameter at compile time. And it's not possible, parameters values are evaluated at runtime. Then it can't be `constexpr` and then you can not use it in a `static_assert`.